# Any fast search algorithms for nested for loops?

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab

I am having a following code…

```
for i=1:100
   for j=1:200

       for k=1:100

             error = DOprocess(i,j,k);

             if(error==const)
               %%Break all loops...
             end
       end

  end
end
```

Now the problem is the DoProcess function takes hell lot of time for each run. But I want to find the combination of I,j,k for which the error code is equal to const. Also I don’t know the internal logic of the DoProcess. I know that if I know that I can use optimization techniques to find the optimal solution. Also the DoProcess can return an error which is equals to const for multiple combinations of I,j and k. I need to find the first occurrence only. So can anyone suggest me an alternative search algorithm instead of these loopings. The code is in Matlab but for c/c++ guys all you need is replace end with} and keep a { at the starting of each for loop. I am ready to implement the search algorithms if required in matlab.

Comment: Buy 100*100*200 processors and do it in parallel.

Comment: With the information you have provided, I doubt that there would be a better way to accomplish this. In the worst case you may have to look through all possible combinations.

Comment: Is there any system to the error code that this `DoProcess` returns (e.g. only ascending error numbers for bigger values of i or j or k?)? Because the only way (I see) to speed up the search *algorithm* itself would be if you can predict at least a trend in the return value. if it's completely random what `DoProcess` returns, its impossible to find it other than brute-force all combinations - only faster (and/or parallel) hardware could make it faster then - a simple solution to use more Cores might be [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP)

Comment: I suggest you dive into the DoProcess function see more details.

Comment: as correctly pointed out, task can leverage parallel execution. as for search algorithm, for a uniformly distributed error values, nothing can be done in fact, you have to infer some info on error destribution in order to try to reduce e.v. of proecessed combinations before first looked for

Comment: Assuming that `DOprocess(i,j,k)` is a continuous function, you could define a cost function as `(const - DOprocess(i,j,k))^2` and try a simple optimization algorithm like `fmincon` for example to find the optimal `i`,`j` and `k`. If it isn't then you will have to brute force it as others have said. But I would think there is a good chance it has reasonable behavior and thus can be optimized.

Comment: I agree with you all that without knowing the implementation of the Doprocess we can't make it fast.Also i am not using multi-threading as it is very expensive tool box in matlab. Anyway i am looking for a similar solution that was suggested by @Dan .. Anyway thank you all for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any extra information of DoProcess function,
if (i, j, k) result do not change all the time, two possible approaches for optimization in practice:

1. do this offline, and cache expected (i, j, k) combinations
2. or, do this once in online environment, and cache. avoid duplicate calculation.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine them as below sample:

```
    max = 100*200*100;
    for (n = 0:max) {
        temp = n;
        i = temp % 100+1;
        temp/=100;
        j = temp % 200+1;
        temp/=200;
        k = temp % 100+1;

        error = DOprocess(i,j,k);

        if(error==const)
            break;
        end
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that will cause a speedup, rather the reverse, with all those modulo and division operations...

Comment: It wont speedup, however it can avoid to many nested for loop and better managed if there is any code refactor.

Comment: hm, that code doesn't look simpler but rather more complex, I don't see how it would simplify refactoring

Comment: This transformation of for-loops is only usefull if you want to parallelize. If you replace this single for with a parfor it might be faster. Could also be slower than replacing a single loop in the original code because of increased overhead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an algorithm optimization, but you could execute this code in parallel (assuming there are no dependencies between iterations (DOprocess).

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know details of DoProcess function, it is not possible to further optimize the code.

If you somehow get the implementation of the function, you could unroll at least one loop, and use SIMD functions (almost every processor support at least partially).

If you just want your computing to finish faster, then you may try to add more threads, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to increase the speed is vectorisation within DOprocess and accept a vector at least for one input.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Such vectorised code is faster because overhead for loops is removed or exists only once per vector. Additionally, many of the basic operations are very efficient for large data sets and use multi-threads to calculate. This does not require the parallel toolbox.